# Grails application holder error

Tags: grails

I am working in grails 2.4.0 and installed excel-import 1.0.0 plugin to the project. While compiling the project it is generating an error that could not resolve the class Application Holder. Please help.

Comment: That plugin is out of date and will not work with grails 2.4 unless it can be updated by someone

Comment: What is the work around for this particular problem.

Comment: You could download the plugin and update it to use injected objects instead of the deprecated holder classes

Comment: Version 1.0.1 is 2.4.x compatible.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. You can get the version 1.0.1 of the plugin here https://github.com/jbarmash/grails-excel-import

Or if you prefer, add this url to the repositories section in BuildConfig.groovy

```
mavenRepo "http://maven.ala.org.au/repository/"
```

I found that this repository has the latest version of the plugin (at least it compiles with grails 2.4.4, real tests are yet to be made)

Then add this two entries to the plugins section

```
compile ":excel-import:1.0.1"
compile ":joda-time:1.5"
```

Comment: "http://maven.ala.org.au/repository/" is timing out, did the repo get cancelled? Any idea where else to get this?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the repo no longer works.
However, for grails 3 the excel import plugin has been updated 
http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/excel-import

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your plugin to the latest 1.0.1 version. It was made 2.4.x compatible.

Comment: how? What repo to use?